# How to put a table in Longtable

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

I have created a table. I used template of springer which has a `\documentclass[twocolumn]` class. the table is shown in the following figure:

[image]

How to active the auto-break of my table, i mean that I want to replace automatic the part of the table which penetrates the limits to next page as shown in that picture :

[image]

Comment: The longtable environment from the longtable package offers exactly this feature. If you need page breaks inside of a table that uses X columns from tabularx, use xltabular instead.

Comment: Just saw that you use a twocolumn documentclass as have a quite narrow table. In that case you might want to take a look at the xtab package.

Comment: posting a picture of some blue squares doesn't help anyone give you any help You should post a small example showing what you did and explain what error you got and show the output from your test document. No need to show your original data every word can be `foo` as long as it shows the problem you are asking about,